# Ввод в wxWidgets в TextCtrl

Tags: c++, типы, wxwidgets

Мне нужны целые числа при вводе в TextCtrl но он принимает только wxString. Как можно безопасно форматировать wxString в int с помощью C++?

Comment: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Converting_everything_to_and_from_wxString

Comment: А еще можете рассмотреть использование [wxSpinCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_spin_ctrl.html) , или  [специального валидатора](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_integer_validator.html).